# how to avoid clear the file object when the second click on the file input button?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I use the multiple file input, I select some images and preview them, while when I secondly click the file input button , the first select data lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a file input click append another file input and hide the current one.View
[Open several times multiple file input without losing earlier selected files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394126/open-several-times-multiple-file-input-without-losing-earlier-selected-files)

Comment: It's a workable one, I'm resolve to a one like the jquery-file-upload.  https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/